# Hazelcast localKeySet

Tags: hazelcast

I'm working with hazelcast version 3.10. I am trying to work with map localKeySet() and the following happens:

- If I work without including a MapStore, localKeySet() works
  correctly: in each local node, KeySet () returns a reduced set of
  keys.
- If I add a MapStore in the map configuration, localKeySet() would
  seem to not work correctly: in each local node, localKeySet() returns
  all keys in the map.

I configured the map with this function:

```
private MapConfig mapConfigurationAux (Config config, String name, int backupCount, boolean statisticsEnabled, int mapStoreDelay,
        MapStore implementationMapStore) {

        MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig (name);
        mapConfig.setBackupCount(backupCount);
        mapConfig.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT);
        mapConfig.setStatisticsEnabled(statisticsEnabled);

        if (implementationMapStore! = null) {
            MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = new MapStoreConfig();
            mapStoreConfig.setEnabled(true);
            mapStoreConfig.setImplementation(implementationMapStore);
            mapStoreConfig.setWriteDelaySeconds(mapStoreDelay);
            mapStoreConfig.setWriteBatchSize(100);
            mapStoreConfig.setInitialLoadMode(InitialLoadMode.LAZY);
            mapConfig.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreConfig);
        }
        return mapConfig;
    }
```

What I can be doing wrong?

Comment: `localKeySet()` does not trigger MapStore calls so it should be something else. How many members did you have when you do the call? Maybe there was some topology change, have you checked logs?

Comment: We have 5 nodes. With the MapStore configured and the 5 nodes are running, I add an element to the map and when calling localKeySet () on each node, the key of the new element is returned in all cases.

Comment: Doesn't do this for me. Are you able to post a demo ?

Comment: I found the problem

As expected, I had a Hazelcast configuration problem. In the interface that set the NetWorkConfig, it was setting 127.0.0.1 in all instances of the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem As expected, I had a Hazelcast configuration problem. In the interface that set the NetWorkConfig, it was setting 127.0.0.1 in all instances of the cluster.

```
NetworkConfig network = cfg.getNetworkConfig();
network.setPort(port).setPortAutoIncrement(true);
network.setPublicAddress(publicAddress);
network.getInterfaces().addInterface("127.0.0.1").setEnabled(true);
```